# How can I stop Nightwatch process on test failure?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am running nightwatch without the source option, which means I am running all the tests located in the `src_folders`.

I am using the retries option like this:

```
nightwatch --retries=3
```

My problem is that when a test suite fails, nightwatch processes all the next test suites. I want nightwatch to exit. I am running nightwatch in my gitlab CI job and I don't want to wait for all the tests to end to finish the job. As soon as nightwatch detects an error that failed 3 times (with the retries) I want it to stop.

The only workaround I found so far is to launch all my test suites manually so that any test suite that would fail would exit with an error code and stop my gitlab job:

```
nightwatch test/test1 --retries=3
nightwatch test/test2 --retries=3
nightwatch test/test3 --retries=3
```

but it is not really confortable.

Any options I missed ?

Comment: I faced something similar, but I wanted my tests to continue even after failure. So included in my config file `skip_testcases_on_fail: false`. For your case may be you can try something like `skip_testcases_on_fail: true`.

Comment: sadly this is already whats happening by default. The option `skip_testcases_on_fail` only skips the next step within the same test suite. I'm looking for something that would cancel the next testsuites.